# Read value from file & put it into a variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to read file that contains a single line

```
cpu=msm8998
```

I need to grab the value after "=" and assign it to a variable. What's the simplest way to do it ? without using cat if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this text is in a file `cpu.txt`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

CPU_FILE="cpu.txt"

CPU=`awk -F= '{ print $2 }' "$CPU_FILE"`
echo "\$CPU = $CPU"
```

Using `awk` to split on the `=` (that's the `awk -F=`), output the 2nd field ( `{ print $2 }`), then store the output of all that into `$CPU` with back-tick enclosure (I'm not sure of the proper name for this, if any).

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read) builtin:

```
IFS== read name value < file
echo "${value}"
```

`read` splits the input into fields delimited by `IFS` the shell's *internal field separator*. In your example the field separator is `=`.

Alternatively, just [*source*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-source) the file:

```
source file
echo "${cpu}"
```

Answer (score 3):

If your input file is just that one line, then you should source it:

```
$ cat input  

cpu=msm8998
$ echo $cpu 

$ . input
$ echo $cpu
msm8998
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
my_var="$(cut -d= -f2 my_file.txt)"
```

The `cut` command basically says to split each line in my_file.txt into fields separated by equals signs, and print only the second field.

Test session:

```
$ echo cpu=msm8998 > my_file.txt
$ my_var="$(cut -d= -f2 my_file.txt)"
$ echo "$my_var"
msm8998
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's really all that's in the other file, I'd just source it, the example you gave is a valid shell assignment:

```
$ cat file
pu=msm8998
$ cat using_it
#!/bin/bash

. file
printf '%s\n' "$cpu"

$ ./using_it
msm8998
```